# How to use react router v6 in chrome extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, react-router, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

please explain this in detail.
I am using the below code for routing but I am not getting any component rendered on screen. my screen is blank.

This is my GitHub link for detailed code structure.
https://github.com/nadimakhtar97/tatkal-extension

This is Layout.js

```
import { Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import React from 'react'
import Welcome from './Welcome'
import Options from './Options'
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";


function Layout() {
    return (
        <Flex>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Welcome />} />
                    <Route path="options" element={<Options />} />
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Flex>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

This is Popup.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Box, ChakraProvider, Heading } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Layout from './Layout';



function Popup() {

  return (
      <ChakraProvider>
        <Layout />
      </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

render(<Popup />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Is `Layout` being rendered somewhere? Are there any errors? I don't see any issues with this specific code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes Layout is being rendered. In Popup.js

Comment: I don't reproduce any rendering issues of your code in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-react-router-v6-in-chrome-extension-h0scs2) so I'm suspecting any issues are elsewhere. You've tagged this post with some chrome extension related tags, can you share that part of your project?

Comment: I have added my github link (https://github.com/nadimakhtar97/tatkal-extension). You can clone it and see the issue on your computer.

Comment: Extensions don't have a web server so the root path is not `/` but the actual file name of the popup page. You can either specify it explicitly or switch the router to hash mode.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MemoryRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the `useLocation()` hook outside the `<Router />` component which is not allowed and prevents the entire component from being rendered.

**Wrong:**

```
const Popup: React.FC = () => {
  const location useLocation();

  return (
    <Router>
      //...
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**Correct:**

```
const Popup: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <PopupContent />
    </Router>
  );
};

const PopupContent: React.FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```